# How to trigger a postback button to open another structured messages in facebook messenger chatbot

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, chatbot

I'm a newbie on programming, and I've successfully running the example from [Facebook Messenger Platform - quick start](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/guides/quick-start) case. But I'm facing a problem when doing some little changes on the original example:

I'd like to make a postback button click event to trigger another structured messages.When user click the 'coffee' button inside the menu page, it will show up another structure messages which is the coffee page.

[UI Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJA0L.jpg)

I've used a if condiction to check the

```
JSON.stringify(event.postback.payload)
```

is the specific string (which should be 'coffee'),but it didn't display another structured messengers when I click the 'coffee' button in the menu page.

And here is my webhook code below:

```
app.post('/webhook/', function (req, res) {
let messaging_events = req.body.entry[0].messaging
for (let i = 0; i < messaging_events.length; i++) {
    let event = req.body.entry[0].messaging[i]
    let sender = event.sender.id
    if (event.message && event.message.text) {
        let text = event.message.text
        if (text === 'menu') {
            sendMenuMessage(sender)
            continue
        } else if (text === 'coffee') {
            sendCoffeeMessage(sender)
            continue
        }
        sendTextMessage(sender, "Text received, echo: " + text.substring(0, 200))
    }

    if (event.postback) {
        let text = JSON.stringify(event.postback.payload)
        sendTextMessage(sender, "Postback.payload received: " + text.substring(0, 200), token)

        if (text === 'coffee') {
            sendCoffeeMessage(sender)
        }

        continue
    }
}
res.sendStatus(200)})
```

And there're 2 structured messenger which included:
1. A menu page (display all kinds of product)
2. A coffee page (display only coffee)

1.Menu page
To open the menu page, there has a function call sendMenuMessage:

```
function sendMenuMessage(sender) {
let messageData = {
    "attachment": {
        "type": "template",
        "payload": {
            "template_type": "generic",
            "elements": [{
                "title": "Our Menu",
                "subtitle": "Click buttons to see more",
                "image_url": "img.jpg",
                "buttons": [{
                    "type": "postback",
                    "title": "Coffee",
                    "payload": "coffee",
                }, {
                    "type": "postback",
                    "title": "Tea",
                    "payload": "tea",
                }],
            }]
        }
    }
}
request({
    url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages',
    qs: {
        access_token: token
    },
    method: 'POST',
    json: {
        recipient: {
            id: sender
        },
        message: messageData,
    }
}, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
        console.log('Error sending messages: ', error)
    } else if (response.body.error) {
        console.log('Error: ', response.body.error)
    }
})}
```

2.Coffee page
To open the coffee page, there has a function call sendCoffeeMessage:

```
function sendCoffeeMessage(sender) {
let messageData = {
    "attachment": {
        "type": "template",
        "payload": {
            "template_type": "generic",
            "elements": [{
                "title": "Americano",
                "subtitle": "5$",
                "image_url": "img2.jpg",
                "buttons": [{
                    "type": "postback",
                    "title": "Detail",
                    "payload": "americano_detail",
                }],
            }, {
                "title": "Latte",
                "subtitle": "5.5$",
                "image_url": "img3.jpg",
                "buttons": [{
                    "type": "postback",
                    "title": "Detail",
                    "payload": "latte_detail",
                }],
            }]
        }
    }
}
request({
    url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages',
    qs: {
        access_token: token
    },
    method: 'POST',
    json: {
        recipient: {
            id: sender
        },
        message: messageData,
    }
}, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
        console.log('Error sending messages: ', error)
    } else if (response.body.error) {
        console.log('Error: ', response.body.error)
    }
})}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check below code

```
console.log(JSON.stringify('coffee') === 'coffee')
//false
```

The difference is

```
console.log(JSON.stringify('coffee'))
//'"coffee"'
console.log('coffee')
//'coffee'
```

This means the first one is the string including double quotes. Because that's the expression of string in json format.